# Why is my shared_ptr able to construct implicitly from a raw pointer?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm putting a class in my app under `std::shared_ptr`, converting existing code.  My understanding is that `shared_ptr`'s constructor from a raw pointer is explicit (e.g., http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/), and that makes a great deal of sense to me.  However, I'm seeing a weird thing in my app where the constructor seems to me to be acting as if it is implicit.  I don't understand how this possible.

First of all, I have a `typedef` for my `shared_ptr` type:

`typedef std::shared_ptr<EidosPropertySignature const> EidosPropertySignature_CSP;`

Then I have some code where I construct a new object and add it to a vector of shared pointers:

```
std::vector<EidosPropertySignature_CSP> properties;

properties.emplace_back(new EidosPropertySignature(...constructor parameters...));
```

This compiles without even a warning.  I don't see how – the result of `new EidosPropertySignature` is an `EidosPropertySignature *`, which should not be implicitly convertible to the `EidosPropertySignature_CSP` that the vector holds, right?  I would very much like this construct to produce a compile error, as I thought that it would.  Why doesn't it, and is there a way for me to modify my approach so that it does?

Comment: As you say yourself, shared_ptr has an explicit constructor accepting a raw pointer. That constructor is called. Why would you expect this not to work?

Comment: I do not call the explicit constructor.  I simply pass an `EidosPropertySignature *` to `emplace_back()`.  The conversion is therefore done implicitly.  Or perhaps I don't understand what it means for a constructor to be declared `explicit`?  But I sure thought I understood that!  :-O  I would expect to have to do something like `emplace_back(EidosPropertySignature_CSP(new ...))` or `emplace_back(shared_ptr<EidosPropertySignature const>(new ...))`.  Isn't that the whole point of a constructor being explicit?

Comment: @bhaller The whole point of `emplace_back` vs `push_back` is that `emplace_back` takes arguments for the constructor of the element type and not an instance of the element type directly.

Comment: From Michael Kenzel's answer below, I now understand.  I'll comment further on his answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion here. `emplace_back` forwards its arguments directly to the constructor of the element type to construct the new element [[sequence.reqmts]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/containers#tab:containers.sequence.optional):

> Appends an object of type `T` constructed with `std​::​forward<​Args​>(​args)...`.

Thus, `emplace_back` is essentially a direct constructor call. `push_back`, on the other hand, won't work because that would actually require a conversion…

On a purely conceptional level, implicit conversions are about allowing a value of some type to be converted to a value of a different type *if necessary*, possibly as part of a longer conversion sequence. Conversions are about building bridges. With an implicit conversion, you tell the compiler: here's a bridge from `A` to `B`, you may use it to get around. With an explicit conversion, you say: here's a bridge from `A` to `B`, use it only if I explicitly told you to go to `B`; in particular, don't use it if you just want to make your way to somewhere else over `B`. When you write `emplace_back`, you *explicitly* say "construct an element". `emplace_back` *explicitly* expresses that an object of the element type be created. You *explicitly* told the compiler to go to `B`. There is nothing implicit about `emplace_back`…

Comment: Approved you since you got there first.  :->  But this still seems very weird to me.  To me, the point of emplace_back is that the object is constructed in place rather than having to be copied/moved into place.  The fact that that is done by forwarding its arguments to the constructor seems like kind of an implementation detail; it seems to me that it shouldn't get one out of the requirement of explicitly constructing.  (I don't mean my compiler is wrong, I mean I wish the standard required a more explicit construction in this situation.)

Comment: In particular, what bugs me is that looking just at the line `properties.emplace_back(new EidosPropertySignature(...constructor parameters...));` it is not visually apparent that the new object has been placed under `shared_ptr`; that fact is invisible to the reader of the code unless they go up to look at the definition of the vector and see that it's a vector of `shared_ptr` not of raw pointers.  That makes proofreading my code for correctness much more challenging; the conversion is hidden, where in other situations it would have to be, well, *explicit*.

Comment: @bhaller Maybe just use `std::make_shared` in place of raw `new` call?

Comment: @bhaller `explicit` constructors prevent implicit conversions e.g. in function argument passing. `emplace_back` *always* constructs an object of the element type. Therefore there is no surprise conversion here. If you pass a pointer constructed with `new` directly to a function, then you are always saying that that function takes ownership of the pointer in some way. There is no surprise in that either. Passing `new` to a `emplace_back` of a raw pointer `vector` would be inconsistent with ownership semantics. You need to know the element type of the vector in any case.

Comment: @bhaller Disallowing `explicit` constructors in `emplace_back` would make it impossible to skip the move construction from a temporary required to insert a new element using an explicit constructor. That may cause issues with types that are not easily movable. I would also suggest simply not using `new`. If you always use `make_shared` there will be no issue.

Comment: @R2RT, Yeah, that's messy because of details I didn't show in this simplified example.  To construct one of these objects, you first `new` it up, then you can call methods that modify it, and those methods return `this` so you can chain them, like `new A()->B()->C()`; so I can't use `make_shared` without changing this very convenient design (since `B()` and `C()` have no way to return the `shared_ptr`, since `this` is a raw pointer).  Grr.

Comment: @walnut, I find that reasoning unconvincing.  If I tell you that a line of code in my app says `myVector.emplace_back(new Foo(5));`, and ask you whether that `Foo` object is now under `shared_ptr` or not, you cannot answer, right?  That is my point.  The conversion to `shared_ptr` is hidden.  Yes, the vector has taken ownership of the object, clearly; but what *kind* of ownership?  That is hidden, even though the constructor is explicit.  I find that to be very deceptive (although perhaps necessary for the technical reason you describe).

Comment: @bhaller `properties.emplace_back([](){ auto a = std::make_shared<A>(); a->B()->C(); return a; });`

Comment: @bhaller The point of `emplace_back` is to construct an object in place. "Constructing in place" logically implies that a constructor is called. What else could it possibly do? Conversions are about obtaining a value of type `T` from a value of some type that is not `T`. Conversions only ever enter the picture when what you are given is not what you need. `emplace_back` construcs a new element using the arguments that its given. You are already calling a constructor. The only conversions that can possibly happen are to make the arguments match the constructor that is being called…

Comment: @walnut Ugh.  My nice simple line of code (a pattern that is repeated hundreds of times in my code) has just become very gross.  :-<

Comment: @bhaller In most cases your line `new A()->B()->C()` will cause problems anyway, because it is not safe if either `B()` or `C()` may throw exceptions. Alternative since C++17: `properties.emplace_back(std::make_shared<A>())->B()->C();`, but behaves differently under exceptions.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel: "You are already calling a constructor."  Yes, but *which* constructor?  Looking at the `emplace_back()` line, one would never guess that it is calling an explicit constructor to make a `shared_ptr`.  To me the whole point of `explicit` is that this sort of magic is not done for you under the hood; to put something under `shared_ptr` you have to say so *explicitly*.  Anyway, I doubt I'm going to change any minds here, but my point is: as a relatively novice C++ user, this behavior is extremely surprising and seems like a very dangerous source of bugs.

Comment: @bhaller `emplace_back` explicitly specifies that an object be created. There is nothing implicit about this. An explicit conversion tells the compiler to not create a value of the particular type using that conversion unless explicitly told to do so. When you write `emplace_back`, you do *explicitly* tell the compiler to create a value of the given type… I also added a note on this to my answer above.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel If the vector were declared as `std::vector<EidosPropertySignature *> properties;` instead, the exact same `emplace_back()` call would *not* create an object.  So you cannot look at the `emplace_back()` call and tell whether or not an object is going to be created.  Therefore the object creation is *not* explicit.  You may agree with that decision by the language designers, there may be good reasons for it, etc.; but by any normal human understanding of the word "explicit", the fact that the raw pointer I pass to `emplace_back()` gets put under `shared_ptr` is *not* explicit.

Comment: @bhaller of course it would create an object. It would create an element in the vector, which, in that case, would then be an object of type `EidosPropertySignature*`. You cannot have a vector the elements of which are not objects. The element type of an `std::vector` must be an object type. What would it even mean to have a container the elements of which are not objects!? There is no situation in which `emplace_back` can ever return without an object having been created…

Comment: If you want to say that it is explicit according to the C++ standard's definition of "explicit", yes, fine; that is tautological, since the standard defines what "explicit" is and thus whatever the standard says is explicit is explicit.  But all that really means is that the standard has redefined the word "explicit" to mean something other than what any normal non-C++-programmer person would understand the word "explicit" to be.  Anyway, I don't intend to debate this further; I understand the behavior now, and have dealt with it, so thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [std::vector::emplace_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back):

> The element is constructed through `std::allocator_traits::construct`, which typically uses placement-new to construct the element in-place at the location provided by the container. The arguments args... are forwarded to the constructor as `std::forward<Args>(args)...`.

What happens under the hood is essentially:

```
new (storage) EidosPropertySignature_CSP(<emplace_back args>)
```

Which invokes the explicit constructor of `EidosPropertySignature_CSP`.

Answer (score 1):

[`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) constructs the element in-place directly from the arguments being passed.

> The element is constructed through `std::allocator_traits::construct`, which typically uses placement-new to construct the element in-place at the location provided by the container.

Note that [`std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct) constructs the element as `::new (static_cast<void*>(p)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` at last, which is [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization#Notes); the constructor of the element type is `explicit` or not doesn't matter.

(emphasis mine)

> Direct-initialization is more permissive than copy-initialization: **copy-initialization only considers non-explicit constructors and non-explicit user-defined conversion functions, while direct-initialization considers all constructors and all user-defined conversion functions**.

On the other hand, [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) takes `shared_ptr` as parameter type, when a raw pointer being passed it has to be converted to `shared_ptr` implicitly, which is ill-formed because `explicit` converting constructor won't be considered in [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

Answer (score 1):

Because with the usage of `emplace_back`, it is not implicit.

That function will look something like `template<class... Args> reference emplace_back(Args&&... args)`, so in this case you have one argument, `EidosPropertySignature *`, so no problem there.

The `std::shared_ptr` constructor will then be called with `std::forward<Args>(args)...`, which can call the explicit constructor.

```
template<class T, class... Args> T construct(Args...args)
{
    return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
int main()
{
    int *x = new int();
    std::shared_ptr<int> a = x; // error 
    std::shared_ptr<int> b(std::forward<int*>(x)); // OK
    std::shared_ptr<int> c = construct<std::shared_ptr<int>>(x); // OK
}
```